# Profiling info for an opencl command?

Tags: profiling, opencl

I am trying to measure the execution time of a command using profiling info.
This is my code

```
cl_event profEvent;
cl_ulong timeStart,timeStop;
ciErr=clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(cqCommandQueue,ckKernel,1,NULL,&szGlobalWorkSize,NULL,0,NULL,profEvent);
ciErr=clWaitForEvents(1,&profEvent);
clGetEventProfilingInfo(profEvent,CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END,sizeof(timeStop),&timeStop,NULL);
clGetEventProfilingInfo(profEvent,CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START,sizeof(timeStart),&timeStart,NULL);
printf("\nstart=%ld",timeStart);
printf("\nstop=%ld",timeStop);
printf("\nTime after profiling in SUB is \t\t%Ld",timeStart-timeStop);
```

As per the stuff found over net, this should work fine, but I am getting the following output

```
start=6492816
stop=0
Time after profiling in SUB is          6492816

error -58 in NDRANget
```

Now `-58` indicates invalid event and I am unable to figure this thing out how to get the event working?
Please show me how to correct this problem.

Thanks
Piyush

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event has to be passed as a pointer, so it can return the event object in the call.

It should be like this:

```
ciErr=clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(cqCommandQueue,ckKernel,1,NULL,&szGlobalWorkSize,NULL,0,NULL,&profEvent);
```